# "No module named gdata" when trying to use gdata in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio, gdata

I'm trying to use gdata in Python 2.7 with Visual Studios. I installed using pip, and tried manually installing. Despite this anytime I try running the code, I get a "No module named gdata" from VS, even though `pip list` says it's installed

Comment: Where did pip install it, and what is the value of `sys.path` in VS?

Comment: Running what code?  Does the top of your code have "import gdata"?

Comment: The error message "No module named gdata" suggests that he is trying to import it.  If he were just trying to use it without importing, the error would be "NameError: name 'gdata' is not defined" instead.

Comment: I am using 'import gdata'

Comment: Perhaps the Python being used by Visual Studio is different. Check from within python running o=in VS using `import pip` and the `print(pip.get_installed_distributions())`.